# Каким образом отправить большое сообщение?

Tags: python, rsa, aes, encryption

использую библиотеку rsa (https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#generating-keys), читая документацию не совсем понимаю как зашифровать большое сообщение.

*Здесь я специально генерирую ключи на 512, чтобы показать ошибку:*

```
import rsa

(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(512)

public_key = pubkey.save_pkcs1('PEM')
file_out = open("public.pem", "wb")
file_out.write(public_key)
file_out.close()

private_key = privkey.save_pkcs1('PEM')
file = open("private.pem", "wb")
file.write(private_key)
file.close()
```

*А здесь уже шифрую свое сообщение:*

```
import rsa

with open('public.pem', "rb") as publicfile:
    pkeydata = publicfile.read()
pubkey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pkeydata)

message = (
    "Жил на опушке дремучего леса бедный дровосек со своей женой и двумя детьми.").encode('utf8')
crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, pubkey)

file = open('sms.bin', "wb+")
file.write(crypto)
file.close()
```

*И ожидаемо получаю ошибку, что текст больше самого ключа:*

```
OverflowError: 137 bytes needed for message, but there is only space for 53
```

Каким образом я могу избежать этого не меняя размер ключа? Мне бы очень помогло объяснение с примерами.

Comment: Ну у вас же даже в тегах aes указан. Вы создаёте случайный ключ. Сообщение шифруете этим ключом в при помощи AES. А вот сам ключ шифруете через RSA

Comment: И это написано в разделе 5.4.1 по вашей ссылке